# Linq Sum(a+b) different than Sum(a) + Sum(b)

Tags: c#, linq

When we use a *nullable* type like `int?` or `decimal?`, The `Sum(a+b)` sometimes differs from `Sum(a)+Sum(b)`

**Working example**:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public int? One { get; set; }
    public int? Two { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = new List<SomeClass>()
                   {
                       new SomeClass { One = 1, Two = 2 },
                       new SomeClass { One = 1, Two = 2 },
                       new SomeClass { One = 1, Two = 2 },
                       new SomeClass { One = 1, Two = 2 },
                       new SomeClass { Two = 2 }
                   };
    Console.WriteLine(list.Sum(_ => _.One + _.Two)); // 12 // wrong
    Console.WriteLine(list.Sum(_ => _.One) + list.Sum(_ => _.Two)); // 14 
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

One would expect both sums (printed on the `Console`) to write out `14`. But it seems the first one ignores some elements.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Looks like it's behaving as specified to me. You need to understand that `null + 2 == null`, but `Sum` ignores `null` values.

Comment: An ugly work-around is: `list.Sum( _ => ( _.One ?? 0 ) + ( _.Two ?? 0 ) ) );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simply because the last element:

```
new SomeClass { Two = 2 }
```

has no `One`, in that case `One` is `null` and `null+a` with `a` a non-`null` integer is `null`.

Now as is specified in [`Linq.Sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548890%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), the sum ignores `null` values. Thus the last item doesn't count.

This problem is not encountered in the second version because the sum over `One`s will sum all items except the last one, and the sum over the `Two`s will sum over all items.

As @Chris argues, you can indeed use the [Null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) `One ?? 0`. This operator returns `0` in case `One` is `null`, in that case, even if one of the arguments is `null`, it will sum up with zero and thus return a number.